# Median Program in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement median in Python, but when I run the script, it doesn't work properly. But just stop, nothing else happens.

**Median Program**

```
data = []
value = input("Enter a value (blank line to quit): ")

while value != " ":
     value = float(value)

data.append(value)
value = input("Enter a value (blank line to quit): ")
data.sort()

if len(data) == 0:
    print("No values were entered: ")
elif len(data) % 2 == 1:
     median = data[len(data) // 2]
     print("The median of those values is", median)
else:
    median = (data[len(data) // 2] + data[len(data) // 2 - 1]) / 2
    print("The median of those values is", median)
```

Comment: Why do you call it "mean" in the title when you want the median?

Comment: what does "does not work properly" mean? How do you launch it? What do you give as an input?

Comment: I launch it in anaconda, and when I run it, and try to input a number, the program doesn't do anything, literally anything.

Comment: Because it gets stuck in the `while` loop. Nothing can ever break out of that other than intervention; it doesn't ask for any new input or anything, it just goes round and round once you enter the loop

Comment: why, I can't see it, sorry

Comment: `value = float(value)` can _never_ give `value == " "` so `value != " "` is always true. Those 2 lines of code run for eternity.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code had two mistakes.

First one, the code has a problem of indentation.

```
while value != " ":
     value = float(value)

data.append(value)
```

In this code, value will never be appended in data, as this is outside of the while block. `value != " "` will always be evaluated at `True` as `value` will never change.

The second one is that blank line is not `" "` but `""`. So in the indentation-fixed code, it will result in an error.

> cannot convert " " to float

Here is the fixed code

```
data = []
value = input("Enter a value (blank line to quit): ")

while value != "":
    value = float(value)

    data.append(value)
    value = input("Enter a value (blank line to quit): ")
    data.sort()

if len(data) == 0:
    print("No values were entered: ")
elif len(data) % 2 == 1:
     median = data[len(data) // 2]
     print("The median of those values is", median)
else:
    median = (data[len(data) // 2] + data[len(data) // 2 - 1]) / 2
    print("The median of those values is", median)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Just a quick question, what is learning debug in python? do you have some literature to learn that or it is just practice and practice coding ?

Comment: You can use a debugger if you want to, such as pdb or directly with IDEs such as Pycharm. For simple programms you can just add prints !

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use 'while' where 'if' can be used, its going into infinite loop because of that. Use 'if'

```
data = []
value = input("Enter a value (blank line to quit): ")

if value != " ":
 value = float(value)

# rest of the code
```

Comment: Ok, thak you very much for the advice, and sorry just trying to learn programming.

Comment: @Knight no problem, we all make mistakes

Comment: I think OP does want a `while` loop though, so they can have many numbers input (and not a predefined amount like a `for` loop)

Answer (score 1):

After the first input `value` remains the same, so you get stuck in the infinite input. If you want to achieve described functionality, then your code should look like this:

```
data = []

while True:
    value = input("Enter a value (blank line to quit): ")

    if value == '':
        break
    else:
        value = float(value)
        data.append(value)

data.sort()

if len(data) == 0:
    print("No values were entered: ")
    exit(0)

elif len(data) % 2 == 1:
    median = data[len(data) // 2]

else:
    median = (data[len(data) // 2] + data[len(data) // 2 - 1]) / 2

print("The median of those values is", median)
```

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of python is not having to reinvent the wheel yourself every time you sit down to script. [There is already a `statistics` module (standard with python)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) that includes a [`.median()` functionality](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median)

```
import statistics
data = []
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter a value (blank line to quit):\n>>>")
    if user_input == "":
        break
    else:
        data.append(float(user_input)) # probably should catch the errors here
        # ^^ user inputs may not be able to be parsed into float format!
print("Median of input values: {}".format(statistics.median(data)))
```

This example also shows a proper `while` loop that accepts user input until a blank line is input. There is no error catching here (probably a feature you should implement though).

An example run of it:

```
Enter a value (blank line to quit):
>>>56.2
Enter a value (blank line to quit):
>>>26.4
Enter a value (blank line to quit):
>>>700.95
Enter a value (blank line to quit):
>>>
Median of input values: 56.2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am guessing correctly, you want to read one number and press enter, and so on, until user input a blank line.
In this case, the input part should be:

```
data = []
while True:
    value = input("Enter a value (blank line to quit): ")
    if value == " ":
        break
    else:
        data.append(float(value))

data.sort()
```

Now `data` is sorted and you can use your logic to extract the median.

A better approach could be to use the `try` `except` block to check that the value is correct, and break the loop as soon as an invalid number is given (that is, a `ValueError` exception is raised).

```
data = []
while True:
    value = input("Enter a value (blank line to quit): ")
    try:
        data.append(float(value))
    except ValueError:
        break

data.sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a perfect example to use assignment expression (walrus operator) to remove double input prompts. Another example is how to calculate median using ~ operator instead of finding upper middle value you can just negate middle value and take value in the list from the end. For instance ~2 = -3. Using a negative index in the list will find a value from the end.

```
data = []

while value := input("Enter a value (blank line to quit): "):
    data.append(float(value))

data.sort()

if data:
    mid = len(data) // 2
    median = (data[mid] + data[~mid]) / 2
    print(f"The median of those values is {median}")
else:
    print("No values were entered.")
```